# joint_state_publisher like joint_trajectory_action GUI tool

Tags: ros, action, joint-state-publisher, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I like [joint_state_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/joint_state_publisher) for debug of URDF models.
I want to use some GUI tool for debug of gazebo simulation model.

Is there any tool that publishes(?) pr2_controllers_msgs/JointTrajectory.action messages like joint_state_publisher's gui?

I'm using Fuerte and Ubuntu12.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34335/joint_state_publisher-like-joint_trajectory_action-gui-tool/) by [ogutti](https://answers.ros.org/users/2408/ogutti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2012-05-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2012-07-04**:
Hi, I also encountered same situation. Did you already find the tool publishing JointTrajectoryAction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To revive an old question...

I found the easiest way was to load a JointPosition or JointVelocity based controller instead, which should be in the same stack, and feed in the appropriate command.

---

Originally posted by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) with karma: 1103 on 2012-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0